# TypeError: 'ExistingCountries' object is not callable?, Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a random country command in discord.py in a all-in-one bot however I am getting the error TypeError: 'ExistingCountries' object is not callable. Pycountry is imported into the bot

````py
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import time
import youtube_dl
import functools
import itertools
import math
import sys
import traceback
import pycountry
import datetime
from functools import partial
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from async_timeout import timeout
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'is!')
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def randomcountry(ctx):
    c = pycountry.countries()
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(c)}')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make it a list:

```
random.choice(list(pycountry.countries)).name
```

for further reference, you can read the docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/)

Comment: @DTOG I edited it to the correct implementation: sorry for the complications! If the answer was helpful, in a couple of minutes you can click the green checkmark so other users know the correct implementation in reference to your problem. Thanks for asking!